# Can I ask questions about things like Question2Answer or Rainloop Webmail on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I have some questions that I want to ask, but I don't know if it's going to be closed. So I am asking if questions about [Rainloop Webmail](http://rainloop.net) or [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org) are allowed to be asked and if it's going to be closed.

Comment: What sort of questions would you like to ask?

Comment: @mat Things like bugs and how to do things in it.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a support site. If you find bugs in a product, report it to that product's support channel. "How to do things" is hopelessly vague.

Comment: Based on *"Things like bugs and how to do things in it."*, I'd say it's NOT okay to ask questions about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [help -> on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

If you are going to ask questions related to programming then it is totally okay to ask questions about Rainloop Webmail or Question2Answer. In fact we have a tag for [question2answer](/questions/tagged/question2answer). But be sure that you are not asking [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) questions like  broad, unclear, or primarily opinion-based etc.

Comment: So, user2999108, key is *"If you are going to ask questions related to programming"*. (Given the author's comment to the question, *"What sort of questions would you like to ask? -- Things like bugs and how to do things in it."*, I'd say such does NOT fall into "software tools commonly used by programmers". If it did, then Microsoft Word questions would be okay too?)

Comment: @Arjan - I clearly advised *If you are going to ask questions related to programming*. So if you are going to ask questions like "bugs in the tool" or "how to do" probably not on topic.

Comment: The correct tag link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question2answer and shows currently 56 questions. It's better IMO to ask directly in the help forum for the software (running with this software): http://www.question2answer.org/qa/ -- For bug reports there is https://github.com/q2a/question2answer

Answer (score 2):

Why not. As long as it is a programming question, something like, if you're trying to connect with `Rainloop webmail` using some api of theirs which doesn't seem to be working, you can very post a question with your code, the exception trace and a proper description of what is not working (i.e) a very specific problem. That would very much be a valid SO question.

But if your question is gonna be like, *how I can do it* or *can you suggest me the best resource* or *can you help me code* type, then they'll be downvoted and closed, almost immediately.

Read about what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO and also, [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before actually asking the question.